# How to send data using ajax from radio button or checkbox using same jQuery code

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am working on project where questions can have either single choice, or multiple choice, and is fetching from server using ajax. PHP code is

```html
 <?php 
 if($options){
   foreach($options as $option){
    ?>
    <li class="col-lg-4 form-group">
    <?php
      if($choice_type AND $choice_type==1):
    ?>
     <input type="radio" id="options" required value="<?php echo $option->id;?>"> <?php echo $option->option_name;?>
    <?php 
      else:
    ?>
    <input type="checkbox" id="options" required value="<?php echo $option->id;?>"> <?php echo $option->option_name;?>
    <?php 
      endif;
    ?>
    </li>
    <?php
    }
  
 } 
  
 ?>
```

and i was using jquery code

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $('#submit_next').click(function () {
  var qsn = $('#question_id').val();
  var opsn = $('#options').val();
  var data='que='+qsn+'&ans[]='+opsn;
  $.ajax({
  type:"GET",
  url:"<?php echo base_url('questions/save_answer')?>",
  data:data,
  success:function(html) {
  $("#question").html(html);
  }
  });
  return false;
  });
 });
```

Which was working totally fine when i just had radio button, but now i am having both so i need to change code which i thought to be like this.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#submit_next').click(function () {
  var qsn = $('#question_id').val();
  var opsn = [];
  
  $("#options").each(function() {
   if($(this).attr('checked') || attr('selected')) {
    opsn.push.($(this).val());
            }
    
  });

  var data='que='+qsn+'&ans='+opsn;
  $.ajax({
  type:"GET",
  url:"<?php echo base_url('questions/save_answer')?>",
  data:data,
  success:function(html) {
  $("#question").html(html);
  }
  });
  return false;
  });
 });
```

All i want is, if its radio button, i want to receive data on server end in array with single value, or if i have check-box, i will be getting array with multiple values.

For example:

for radio button, i wish

`$option[0]= 2;`

and for check-box, it should be

`$option[0]=>2,$option[1]=>5.`

Help will be deeply appreciated.

Comment: `$("#options").each`?? You are having duplicate `id`s?

Comment: Yeah, I corrected that latter.. thanks for prompt.